# SQL Server 2005 Clustered Index Query Speed

Tags: performance, ssms, sql-execution-plan, clustered-index

Our sites are getting pounded pretty hard so we're taking a look into optimizing some of our existing queries.

While looking into this we ran across several queries whose execution plan was about 4-5 times faster when a simple reference of the clustered index is in the query... for example

If this was the old query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM myTable
WHERE categoryID =  @category
```

the following query would be 4 times faster according to the execution plan in SSMS:

```
SELECT ...
FROM myTable
WHERE categoryID =  @category 
AND lotID = lotID
```

We can't seem to make sense of how this would make the query faster. The clustered index is on lotID but since its doing a comparison against itself how is this helping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

seems pretty obvious to me

your first query is not covered by the clustered index while the second is since lotID is not in the WHERE clause of the first query

You might want to read [SQL Server covering indexes](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-covering-indexes) to see how that all works

you also need to understand that a clustered index IS the data, all the data for a table is in the clustered index. when you create a non clustered index on table that has a clustered index then the non clustered index will have a pointer to the clustered index (since that is where the rest of the data is) unless you can satisfy your query completely by the non clustered index and in that case only the non clustered index will be used...I will stop rambling now

EDIT

I read AND lotID = @lotID
NOT AND lotID = lotID

sometimes you can fake out a clustered index by doing where lotID >0  (picking the lowest number you have) and you will get a seek

So if your smallest lotID = 1 and you add
AND lotID > 0

you could also see a seek instead of a scan, I demonstrate WHERE IndexValue > '' in this post [Is an index seek always better or faster than an index scan?](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/is-an-index-scan-always-better-or-faster)

Comment: This would only be the case if all the columns in the SELECT statement were also in the clustered index. I don't really think that's the case here (although it could be)

Comment: let me reiterate again all the data for a table (not counting row overflow BLOB LOB and image + varchar(max) types ) ARE in the clustered index

Comment: So is it general practice to use a clustered index in the WHERE clause even if it does not affect the results returned but speeds up the query? I've never seen this done.

Comment: your where clause has to be covered by an index for it to do a seek and not a scan (depending on selectivity of the data of course)

Comment: Oh man..I read AND lotID = @lotID...sometimes you can fake out a clustered index by doing where lotID >0  (picking the lowest number you have) and you will get a seek

Comment: try AND lotID >0  and see if that makes a difference

Comment: What seems to work for us is doing a query beforehand storing @maxLotID = (MAX(lotID) - 20000) then in my example query do lotID > @maxLotID ... this did make it about 3 times faster than just a lotID = lotID  :)